# Setting onclick of td to null using Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, onclick

I have a row of buttons that are used to navigate a site. The user inputs information which populates some of the pages of the site. Before the information is inputted, I'd like to disable the ability to click the navigation buttons. The session variables `Session["indexloaded"]` and `Session["build"]` indicate whether the user has inputted the required information. I am currently using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      document.getElementById("buttontable").onclick = function (){
              if ('<%=Session["indexloaded"]%>' === "") {
              $("td").attr("onclick", null);
              alert("(Alert user that the buttons are disabled until they do a certain action)");
              return;
          }else if ('<%=Session["build"]%>' === "") {
              $("td").attr("onclick", null);
              alert("(Alert user that the buttons are disabled until they do a certain action)");
              return;
          }
      }
 });
```

I'd like to disable the following onclick functions. HTML:

```
<table id="buttontable">
    <tr>
        <td class="buttonstyle" onclick="location.href='page1.aspx';" style='text-align: center; width:x%;'>Button 1</td>
        <td class="buttonstyle" onclick="location.href='page2.aspx';" style='text-align: center; width:x%;'>Button 2</td>
        <td class="buttonstyle" onclick="location.href='page3.aspx';" style="text-align: center; width:x%;">Button 3</td>
        <td class="buttonstyle" onclick="location.href='page4.aspx';" style="text-align: center; width:x%;">Button 4</td>
        <td class="buttonstyle" onclick="location.href='page5.aspx';" style="text-align: center; width:x%;">Button 5</td>
        <td class="buttonstyle" onclick="location.href='page6.aspx';" style="text-align: center; width:x%;">Button 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Right now, if a click one of the buttons (tds) while a session === "", the alert will display, but I will still be redirected to the destination identified in the onclick function of that button (td). How can I prevent the redirection? Can this be done with just Javascript, or jQuery for that matter?

Comment: `$( "td").unbind( "click" );`

Comment: @GokhanArik Made the change and I'm still having the same issue as above. The alert will display, but it still ends up redirecting once the alert is closed.

Comment: @GokhanArik I tried that as well. The selected answer ended up working for me. Thanks for the suggestions though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html5 data attribute to accomplish this in this way:

### HTML:

```
<td class="buttonstyle" data-url="page1.aspx" style='text-align: center; width:x%;'>Button 1</td>
<td class="buttonstyle" data-url="page2.aspx" style='text-align: center; width:x%;'>Button 2</td>
       --------------------------------------
       ---------------------------------------
       ---------------------------------------
```

### JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".buttonstyle").click(function(){

     if ('<%=Session["indexloaded"]%>' === "") {
         alert("(Alert user that the buttons are disabled until they do a certain action)");

     }
else {
window.location.href = $(this).data("url");
}
else if ('<%=Session["build"]%>' === "") {

     alert("(Alert user that the buttons are disabled until they do a certain action)");

            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a million! One thing - I swapped the else and the else if. So I ended with `if (session...etc){`, `else if (session...etc){`, `else{ window...etc`

Answer (score 1):

Your original code had slight issue which is corrected here, in case you want make your original concept work without using HTML5.

```
    var areButtonsDisabled = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("buttontable").onclick = function ()
        {
            if(areButtonsDisabled)
            {
                alert("(Alert user that the buttons are disabled until they do a certain action)");
            }
    }

        if ('<%=Session["indexloaded"]%>' === "") {
            $("td").attr("onclick", null);
            areButtonsDisabled = true;
            return;
        }
        else if ('<%=Session["build"]%>' === "") {
            areButtonsDisabled = true;
            $("td").attr("onclick", null);
            return;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("buttontable").onclick = function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ('<%=Session["indexloaded"]%>' === "") {
                $("td").attr("onclick", null);
                alert("(Alert user that the buttons are disabled until they do a certain action)");
                return;
            }
            else if ('<%=Session["build"]%>' === "") {
                $("td").attr("onclick", null);
                alert("(Alert user that the buttons are disabled until they do a certain action)");
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the proper HTML elements, like the `<a>` element for links:

```
<table id="buttontable">
    <tr>
        <td style='text-align: center; width:x%;'><a class="buttonstyle" href="page1.aspx">Button 1</a></td>
        <td style='text-align: center; width:x%;'><a class="buttonstyle" href="page2.aspx">Button 2</a></td>
        <td style='text-align: center; width:x%;'><a class="buttonstyle" href="page3.aspx">Button 3</a></td>
        <td style='text-align: center; width:x%;'><a class="buttonstyle" href="page4.aspx">Button 4</a></td>
        <td style='text-align: center; width:x%;'><a class="buttonstyle" href="page5.aspx">Button 5</a></td>
        <td style='text-align: center; width:x%;'><a class="buttonstyle" href="page6.aspx">Button 6</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then your script becomes much simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttontable").on('click', '.buttonstyle', function(e) {
        if ('<%=Session["indexloaded"]%>' === "" || '<%=Session["build"]%>' === "") {
            alert("(Alert user that the buttons are disabled until they do a certain action)");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

This will add the event handler to handle the click event of all of the `<a>` elements, and if the condition holds true, stop the link from being followed (`e.preventDefault()` stops the navigation). Otherwise, the link is followed like links usually do.